# Python split string with split character and escape character

Tags: python, regex

In python, how can I split a string with an regex by the following ruleset:

1. Split by a split char (e.g. `;`)
2. Don't split if that split char is escaped by an escape char (e.g. `:`).
3. Do the split, if the escape char is escaped by itself

So splitting

```
"foo;bar:;baz::;one:two;::three::::;four;;five:::;six;:seven;::eight"
```

should yield

```
["foo", "bar:;baz::", "one:two", "::three::::", "four", "", "five:::;six", ":seven", "::eight"]
```

My own attempt was:

```
re.split(r'(?<!:);', str)
```

Which cannot handle rule #3

Comment: What happened to the colons between `one:two;::three` when you have split on the semi-colon? Do you need to remove any leading colons but leave the trailing ones? If so, it wouldnt make sense looking at the last two values in your string to be split where the leading colons remain. Also, what pattern have you come up with so far?

Comment: @JvdV: Good catch, those I forgot. Thanks!

Comment: That makes sense now. And what about your own attempt?

Comment: My own attempt was re.split(r'(?<!:);', str) which cannot handle rule #3

Comment: A group looks like ([^:;]|::|:;|:)+, I think?  Should match anything that isn't a split char or escape char, also any :: or :; and finally permitting : on its own.  That only leaves ; with a non-escape character before it unmatched.

Hopefully that gets you closer to a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `regex` module with the following pattern to split on:

```
(?<!:)(?:::)*\K;
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hs3rBy/1)

- `(?<!:)` - Negative lookbehind.
- `(?:::)*` - A non capturing group for 0+ times 2 literal colons.
- `\K` - Reset starting point of reported match.
- `;` - A literal semi-colon.

For example:

```
import regex as re
s = 'foo;bar:;baz::;one:two;::three::::;four;;five:::;six;:seven;::eight'
lst = re.split(r'(?<!:)(?:::)*\K;', s)
print(lst) # ['foo', 'bar:;baz::', 'one:two', '::three::::', 'four', '', 'five:::;six', ':seven', '::eight']
```

Comment: I nearly used the regex in the other answer `(?::[:;]|[^;\n])+` because it doesn't use lookbehind or `\K` which I always have to look up how they work. Before reading this answer, I didn't know about `\K` at all! But that regex doesn't match the empty string. To match the empty string you need a look-behind and the regex becomes long and much harder to read. This solution is simple but it needs `\K`. The reason is, that you cannot have variable-length look-behinds and `\K` can be used to work around that. Here are the docs: http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#resetmatchstart

Comment: @josch, thanks for your comment and kudos. Fun fact: PyPi's regex package actually does non-fixed width lookbehind construct unlike PCRE.

Answer (score 3):

If matching is also an option, and the empty match `''` is not required:

```
(?::[:;]|[^;\n])+
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `:[:;]` Match `:` followed by either `:` or `;`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^;\n]` Match 1+ times any char except `;` or a newline
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQImgz/1)

```
import re

regex = r"(?::[:;]|[^;\n])+"
str = "foo;bar:;baz::;one:two;::three::::;four;;five:::;six;:seven;::eight"
print(re.findall(regex, str))
```

Output

```
['foo', 'bar:;baz::', 'one:two', '::three::::', 'four', 'five:::;six', ':seven', '::eight']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/h3gvRE)

---

If you want an empty match, but not with an escaped delimiter like `field:;;field` you can use the PyPi regex module, asserting not `;` followed by 1+ times a `:` to the left of the current posititon.

```
(?::[:;]|[^;\n]|(?<=(?<!:);+)(?=;))+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nlZEiT/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETv/Yp4SoLixduupR9SK1S6aQM1CZtYq/TfYwoO7DLLPoYJnzR5d8nZPoPnJJhGWkUfi6miqIU03uOjZyjrC4DeEaS3R4A0MREUofEvRjR22U@MdkWItJArENlxSrA/aR5kFfqUiF3JZakagBaw29o73ly3qeZalzmAxqNWTY1aH2XFtLdgOhvrhn6e1T/iJKKuAluXVEF0zj8)

Example

```
import regex as re
s = 'foo;bar:;baz::;one:two;::three::::;four;;five:::;six;:seven;::eight:;;field'
pattern = r'(?::[:;]|[^;\n]|(?<=(?<!:);+)(?=;))+'
res = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(res)
```

Output

```
['foo', 'bar:;baz::', 'one:two', '::three::::', 'four', '', 'five:::;six', ':seven', '::eight:;', 'field']
```

Comment: I `rm -rf`'ed my messages from this section to not distract folks from this question or answer. I will remove this message too in a day

Comment: The version that also returns the empty match does not work correctly if the delimiter before the empty field is escaped. For example this input will wrongly return an empty match: `field:;;field`

Comment: @josch If you don't want that to happen, you can use the regex module like this `(?::[:;]|[^;\n]|(?<=(?<!:);+)(?=;))+` asserting not a : followed by 1 or more ; to the left. See https://regex101.com/r/nlZEiT/1 and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETv/Yp4SoLixduupR9SK1S6aQM1CZtYq/TfYwoO7DLLPoYJnzR5d8nZPoPnJJhGWkUfi6miqIU03uOjZyjrC4DeEaS3R4A0MREUofEvRjR22U@MdkWItJArENlxSrA/aR5kFfqUiF3JZakagBaw29o73ly3qeZalzmAxqNWTY1aH2XFtLdgOhvrhn6e1T/iJKKuAluXVEF0zj8)

Comment: @josch I have updated the answer in  case the comments are removed.

Comment: Thanks but now your answer `(?::[:;]|[^;\n]|(?<=;)(?=;))+` doesn't make much sense anymore as it's clearly incorrect because the question explicitly says that delimiters can be escaped and that regex doesn't support this in case of an empty match. Maybe at least state this problem of that regex so that people who stop reading at that regex know what they are getting themselves into...